# Showing mathematically why non-zero complex eigenvalues lead to oscillations?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to show mathematically why an ODE system's equilibrium exhibits oscillatory behavior if its eigenvalues have non-zero imaginary parts. What is the best/most general way to show this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They key is to investigate the complex exponential function

$$C\exp((a+ib)t) = C\exp(at)\cdot \exp(ibt)$$

The real part corresponds to exponential decay and imaginary part corresponds to frequency of a sine&cosine couple. The only complex exponential that does not oscillate is the one which has frequency $b=0$.

Maybe you can use Euler formula $\exp(ibt) = \cos(bt) + i\sin(bt)$

Comment: I am little confused. What does the imaginary part of the solution signify? Since these equations can be obtained for a real, physical phenomenon, it having an imaginary part is throwing me off.

Comment: It is probably just the word "imaginary" that is throwing you off. Everything in mathematics is a construction of the mind. "Real" numbers can be much sicker than you imagine even though we choose to call them so.

Comment: Bruh. The key to solving my confusion was to understand that the imaginary part arises because we used complex numbers to solve the system. The real part is all that matters in physical significance.